# Flutter : Issue saving Excel file to Downloads path on Android 11 using Excel package and lecle_downloads_path_provider

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am currently working on an application that utilizes the Excel package in Flutter for saving Excel files. To ensure the files are saved in the Downloads path of the device, I have implemented the [lecle_downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/lecle_downloads_path_provider) package (version 0.0.2+8).

The problem I am facing is that while this approach works perfectly fine on devices running Android versions prior to 11, it fails to save the file on Android 11 devices. I understand that Android 11 introduced scoped storage and restricted access to external storage. To address this, I added the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest.xml file. However, I am concerned that this approach might lead to my app being rejected when uploading it to the Play Store.

I also came across the requirement that starting from SDK version 29, specific permissions (audio, video, and photos) are necessary to access external storage. To address this, I integrated the [media_store_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/media_store_plus) package (version 0.0.7) into my project.

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to save the Excel file to the Downloads path on Android 11 devices. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue and ensuring compatibility with Android 11 devices without violating the Play Store guidelines.

PS: I have added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` still not helpful.

Thank you in advance for your help!